# Result mismatch in Image re-sizing using Bi-Linear Interpolation

Tags: image-processing, cuda, image-resizing

I implemented a CUDA function for image resizing using Bilinear Interpolation. The function was supposedly giving correct results (visually), until I tested on a small matrix to check the exact values of the output image. The results I got were different from the results of OpenCV and MATLAB. I can't find any obvious flaw in my algorithm. Can someone help me on this?

### Bilinear Interpolation Device Function:

```
texture<float, cudaTextureType2D> tex32f;

//Device function 
__device__ float blinterp(const float xIndex, const float yIndex)
{
    //floor the coordinates to get to the nearest valid pixel
    const int intX = static_cast<int>(xIndex);
    const int intY = static_cast<int>(yIndex);

    //Set weights of pixels according to distance from actual location
    const float a = xIndex - intX;  
    const float b = yIndex - intY;

    /* _____________________
     *|          |          |
     *|(1-a)(1-b)| (a)(1-b) |
     *|__________|__________|
     *|          |          |
     *| (1-a)(b) |  (a)(b)  |
     *|__________|__________|
     */

    //Compute the weighted average of 4 nearest pixels
    float out   =   (1 - a) * (1 - b)   *   tex2D(tex32f, intX,intY)
                +   (a) * (1 - b)       *   tex2D(tex32f,intX + 1,intY)
                +   (1 - a) * (b)       *   tex2D(tex32f, intX,intY + 1)
                +   (a * b)             *   tex2D(tex32f,intX + 1,intY + 1);

    return out;
}
```

### Resize Kernel:

```
__global__ void kernel_resize(float* dst, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, int dstPitch, float xScale, float yScale)
{
    const int xIndex = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    const int yIndex = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if(xIndex>=dstWidth || yIndex>=dstHeight)   return;

    const unsigned int tid = yIndex * dstPitch + xIndex;

    const float inXindex = xIndex * xScale;
    const float inYindex = yIndex * yScale;

    dst[tid] = blinterp(inXindex,inYindex);
}
```

### Wrapper Function:

```
int resize_32f_c1(float* src,float* dst,int srcWidth,int srcHeight, int srcPitch, int dstWidth,int dstHeight,int dstPitch)
{
    if((srcWidth == dstWidth) && (srcHeight == dstHeight))
    {
        cudaMemcpy2D(dst,dstPitch,src,srcPitch,srcWidth * sizeof(float),srcHeight,cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
        return 0;
    }

    cudaBindTexture2D(NULL,tex32f,src,srcWidth,srcHeight,srcPitch);

    dim3 Block(16,16);
    dim3 Grid((dstWidth + Block.x - 1)/Block.x, (dstHeight + Block.y - 1)/Block.y);

    float x = (float)(srcWidth)/(float)dstWidth;
    float y = (float)(srcHeight)/(float)dstHeight;

    kernel_resize<<<Grid,Block>>>(dst,dstWidth,dstHeight,dstPitch/sizeof(float),x,y);

    cudaUnbindTexture(tex32f);

    return 0;
}
```

## Results (Downscale by 2):

### Input (10 x 10):

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

### MATLAB and OpenCV Output:

```
0   0     0    0    0
0   0.25  0.5  0.25 0
0   0.5   1    0.5  0
0   0.25  0.5  0.25 0
0   0     0    0    0
```

### My Output:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Why are you passing integer coordinates to `tex2D` and why aren't the coordinate properly voxel centred?

Comment: @talonmies... I tried changing the arguments of `tex2D` to `float`. It had no effect. What is voxel centered coordinate? And how do I do that?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674185/understanding-textures-linear-filtering-in-cuda

Comment: @RobertCrovella... actually I'm trying to do full precision interpolation instead of using CUDA's builtin 9 bit interpolation. Also, according to @talonmies' suggestion, I tried centering the pixel coordinate by passing `intX + 0.5f` and `intY + 0.5f` to `tex2D`, but I'm getting the same result again.

Comment: I deleted my answer and comments since they were based on incorrect assumptions about your code.

Comment: @RobertCrovella.. Experimenting with talonmies' suggestion, I eventually found the solution. Now I'm having exactly the same results as MATLAB. Actually I had to add 0.5 to the coordinates inside the kernel, Like this: `const float inXindex = xIndex * xScale + 0.5f;`  Thankyou for the help. :)

Comment: OK why don't you post what you did then, we can call this closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the suggestion provided by @talonmies, I eventually found the cause of the problem.

When calculating the location of the pixel in the input image, the coordinates of the pixel should be pixel-centered, i.e an offset of 0.5 should be added to the calculated coordinates of the pixel. Not only this, the weights of the pixels should also be calculated using the pixel-centered coordinates. The coordinates of the pixel in the input image should be calculated as follows inside the kernel:

```
const float inXindex = xIndex * xScale + 0.5f;
const float inYindex = yIndex * yScale + 0.5f;
```

Alternatively, the `blinterp` function can be modfied as follows:

```
__device__ float blinterp(const float xIndex, const float yIndex)
{
    //round the coordinates to get to the nearest valid pixel
    const int intX = static_cast<int>(xIndex + 0.5f);
    const int intY = static_cast<int>(yIndex + 0.5f);

    //Set weights of pixels according to distance from actual location
    const float a = xIndex - intX + 0.5f;  
    const float b = yIndex - intY + 0.5f;
    .
    .
    .
```